# Does parse support facebook 3.5 sdk?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I've recently upgraded my facebook sdk to 3.5. Now however I seem to be facing this constant error:

Facebook error connect: Write Privacy is not specified. Please tap Cancel to return to **** and try again.

I've split my permissions into two sets as requried (publish\ readonly). The readonly requests work fine, however when I use the following function I get the same error as before. Below, the function:

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser]
    permissions:permissions
    block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!succeeded)
    {
         [self fbResync];
         block(FALSE, error);
    }
    else
    {
        [[self userApi] pingServerWithLogin:
        [[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
        [self readFacebookUserDataWithBlock:block];
    }
}];
```

Why is this happening? How can I overcome this? I've set all the relevant settings in my plist file (all taken from the facebook settings page).

Thank you